# Modify Hotkey for Age of Empires 2

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, age-of-empires-ii-hd

I will probably purchase the remastered edition of Age of Empires 2 when it launches on April 9th on Steam, but at this time I do not have my original copy of the game so I cannot test this feature...

**Question:** Is it possible to assign your own hotkeys for Age of Empires 2 (and expansions)? If not, what is the buzz word for keypads/boards that are tailored for RTS hotkey access (not asking for recommendation, just the industry standard)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can answer it for the original game.  Since the HD version isn't out, and we don't allow questions about unreleased games, I have removed that tag from your question.

Comment: AoE 2 allows you to rebind every hotkey in the game.  I'm not sure I understand the second half of your question.

Comment: The second question pertains to modified keyboards (I think that may be the term). I've heard of keyboards that are smaller for one-handed use.  This way a user can move the mouse and perform hotkeys simultaneously without ever lifting their hands.

Comment: I feel like you could get tons of answers to your second question by asking about hardware setups in a Starcraft community.  The pro / serious AoC community is very small and even some of the best AoC players at the moment use keybindings that are not too far off the default.  I actually haven't heard of anyone using macros to play AoC.

Comment: @jw013 although most of them can be done, I think not *every* hotkey can be rebound, or not in every possible way. I have to check this but I remember being unable to create a specific combination I imagined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can assign an ungodly number of hotkeys through the regular options menu.

Some gaming-oriented keyboards/mice have macro binding ability. The Logitech G105 is one such keyboard, and [this quickstart PDF goes over the basic macro binding process](http://www.logitech.com/assets/42320/6/g105-quick-start-guide.pdf).